# Facebook Meta tags not being used

Tags: facebook, wordpress, meta

In wordpress, I have these meta tags in my header:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://frontgroupdesign.com/1percent/profile/the-billionaire-runner-up-meg-whitman/" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="I voted for Meg Whitman as Ms. 1% of California | Who will you vote for?" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://frontgroupdesign.com/1percent/wp-content/themes/california-1p/images/ca_squeeze.png" />
```

And for some reason its using meta tags that I set yesterday. I tried using facebooks lint/debugger tool to update them, but its still using the old ones.

Any ideas to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me.

[image]

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Ffrontgroupdesign.com%2F1percent%2Fprofile%2Fthe-billionaire-runner-up-meg-whitman%2F

Comment: the facebook debug turns out fine, but if you go to the page and actually try and share it, it uses earlier meta

http://frontgroupdesign.com/1percent/profile/the-billionaire-runner-up-meg-whitman/

Comment: Not when I do it. http://i.stack.imgur.com/s4ZAh.png Right image, right title, right URL. You should fix those special characters in the `og:description`, though.

Comment: That's weird. When i just put the link into facebook, it comes up with the right stuff, but when I click on "share" button on the site, it comes up with the old stuff. Are you encountering that problem as well?

Comment: Could be caching? I don't see any problems http://i.stack.imgur.com/VfI1g.png @Brucep

Comment: Huh, that's what i thought and tried it on a different computer. Oh well, guess i'll try it on one more.

thanks!